# How to add item in list in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

[image: snapshot]

I want that on click of "Add to Cart" button, item will add on "My Cart". Here is my angularJS code

```
app.controller("OnlineShopping", function($scope)
 { 
    $scope.items = [
        {Product:"Moto G2", Desc: "Android Phone", Price: 10999},
        {Product:"The Monk who sold his ferrari", Desc: "Motivational book", Price: 250},
        {Product:"Mi Power Bank", Desc: "Power Bank", Price: 999},
        {Product:"Dell Inspiron 3537", Desc: "Laptop", Price: 45600}
    ];
    $scope.editing = false;
    $scope.addItem = function(item) {
        $scope.items.push(item);
        $scope.item = {};
    };
```

I found some questions here with using `ng-model` and `ng-bing` but it works with textbox, but here I am not taking input from the textbox. Here is my incomplete code for "My Cart"

```
    <h2>My Cart</h2>
        <div style="border: 1px solid blue;">
        </div>
        <table border="1" class="mytable">
        <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
           <td>Description</td>
           <td>Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                  <!-- What should be here -->
        </tr>
       </table>
```

Comment: do you want us to complete your code..or you have some doubts?

Comment: @pankajparkar I just want to know where I am going wrong. Check kathir answers

Comment: I was expecting you to update your question..bdw glad to see your problem is solved

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just need to add the cell values using the . But before that When you click on "Add to Cart" button the item needs to be added to a different variable $scope.myCartItems

```
$scope.addToCart = function(item)
{
$scope.myCartItems.push(item);
}
```

And the template will change like below,

```
<h2>My Cart</h2>
        <div style="border: 1px solid blue;">
        </div>
        <table border="1" class="mytable">
        <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
           <td>Description</td>
           <td>Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in myCartItems">
             <td>{{item.Product}}</td>
<td>{{item.Desc}}</td>
<td>{{item.Price}}</td>
        </tr>
       </table>
```

Take a look at this plnkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/zW7k8J9it1NIJE3hEwWI?p=preview

Comment: works fine after adding `console.log("Adding to the cart"); 
      
   console.log(item);` in my angularJS code. It will be more helpful for me and others also if you can explain what does it do?

Comment: console.log statements are only for debugging purpose, they dont make any difference to the functionality of the method.

Answer (score 0):

It looks good.

Try removing the line

```
$scope.item = {};
```

and also wrap it around a $watch

```
$scope.$watch('items', function(){
      console.log('items changed');
});
```